# Get one value from query without using foreach

Tags: php, pdo

I need to perform multiple queries on a database table, basically my PHP script has to:

1. insert into the table a new user storing his id, name, email;
2. get the id of the newly created user using his email;
3. associate the id with a key and a timestamp.

I am pretty new to PDO and my problem is I can't figure out a smart way to get that one `id` without using a `foreach`, so basically my code is:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(name, surname, email) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $surname . "', '" . $email . "')";
$this->dbconn->query($query);

$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='" . $email . "'";
$data = $this->dbconn->query($query);
$id = $data['id'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(name, surname, email) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $surname . "', '" . $email . "')";
$this->dbconn->query($query);
$id = $this->dbconn->lastInsertId();
```